# Dependency management of inter-dependent projects

Tags: maven

We want to manage the dependency versions centrally, so we come up with a central maven project called commons to manage versions for projects m1 and m2:

```
 commons
    |___pom.xml: 
                 <groupId>commons</groupId>
                 <artifactId> commons </artifactId>
                 <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                 <properties>
                     <m1.version>1.0.0</m1.version>
                     <m2.version>1.0.0</m2.version>
                 </properties>
                 <dependencyManagement>
                     <depencencies>
                         <dependency>
                             <groupId>g1</groupId>
                             <artifactId>m1</artifactId>
                             <version>${m1.version}</version>
                         </dependency>
                         <dependency>
                             <groupId>g2</groupId>
                             <artifactId>m2</artifactId>
                             <version>${m2.version}</version>
                         </dependency>
                     </dependencies>
                 </dependencyManagement>
```

m1 and m2's parent is commons and m1 has dependency to m2:

```
    m1
    |___pom.xml: 
                 <groupId>g1</groupId>
                 <artifactId>m1</artifactId>
                 <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

                 <parent>
                     <groupId>commons</groupId>
                     <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
                     <version>1.0.0</version>
                 </parent>

                 <depencencies>
                         <dependency>
                             <groupId>g2</groupId>
                             <artifactId>m2</artifactId>
                         </dependency>
                 </dependencies>
```

By doing this, I do not have to specify the version of m2.
The problem is, if I now I want to change m2 and m1 will get the changes for m1 by doing:

1. release a new version of m2 from 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT to 1.0.1
2. update in commons  from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1
3. release a new version of commons from 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT to 1.0.1
4. update in m1 the parent reference:

   ```
            <parent>
                <groupId>commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
            </parent>
   ```
5. release a new version of m2 from 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT to 1.0.1
6. update in commons  from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1
7. release a new version of commons from 1.0.1 to 1.0.2

The concern of us is the commons version 1.0.1 is not a consisten version, because m2 and the depended m2 from m1 is not the same.

Did I explain my issue clearly? Could you give some suggestions?

Thank you,
Yashu

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), it is not clear what you really want to achieve. If at all possible, you should have *one* version for the whole project, with all sub-modules. Other structures will lead to a lot of problems, like the one you currently have.

Comment: Yes, putting m1 and m2 into the same maven project as a multi-module project will solve part of the issue, but then imaging that I cannot really release m2 alone but I must fix m1 before I can release m2. This will reduce the flexibility. And also if I have m1 till m50 modules, I believe it is also not optimal to put them in one project.